# WP Scroll to ID on click

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravityforms

I will be really grateful if someone could assist me.

I have a GravityForms form on Wordpress and I want the radio button selected to scroll to the form that appears below.

I found that every button has a unique generated class and every form has a unique generated ID. I tried implementing different JavaScript scripts in the `Insert Header and Footer` plugin.

But nothing I've tried has worked, here is the form:

https://cleanexpert.co.uk/booking/?gpmpn_page=2&postcode=n145ae

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question to include relevant code, as this question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I will read these pages. Thanks for trying to help me being better part of the community. i tried with the code below in the comments and explained what is the problem, I will be very thankful if you can advice me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scroll to anchor not working on Wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762144/scroll-to-anchor-not-working-on-wordpress-page)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    jQuery('.gfield-choice-input').on('click', function(event) {        
     var target = jQuery("#field_1_80");
       // event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 180
        }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: When I tried in Insert Header and Footer plugin, it did not worked. But I added HTML embed from elementor and put the script there. Firtsly I tried with this selector .gfield-choice-input but it locks every button and make it unclickable.

Comment: Also it is not good option because some buttons does not have form below, then I tried targeting every button seperatly.

I selected only the first. It is unclickable and does not select and scroll but when you click for exmaple on the second and then you try to click on the first, it scroll but does not select it, hmm... Thanks a lot for trying to help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Now it works but starts working from the 2nd click, on first it does not work. I just removed the line with preventDefault

Comment: Great! I have updated the code, hope the issue is resolved now :)

Comment: No, there is no change in the behaviour and  I tried remove -180, but still did not work